# Multi-column issue with horizontal scroll

Tags: css

I have a parent div (main) with the horizontal overflow set to auto.  I then have a child element (columns) that has all of my column properties on it.  The problem is that once the content goes further than the viewport I can no longer control the right hand margins or padding as the column only seems to go as far as the viewport.  For example when I put a background color on "columns" the background only goes as far as the edge of the viewport even though the content scrolls further than that.

```
.main {
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.columns {
    background: red;
    column-fill: auto;
    column-width: 670px;
    column-gap: 80px;
    height: 120px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: auto;
}

<div class="main">
     <div class="columns">
           <p></p>
           <p></p>
           <p></p>
           <p></p>
           <p></p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Here is an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/fyG24/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I hope my answer proves useful. Don't forget, if my answer is useful, upvote it. If it solves your issue, click the check mark to "accept" it.

Comment: And, don't forget, you can upvote as many answers as you want, but you can only accept one. Both actions increase the person's reputation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### New Answer: Use Pseudo-Elements to Help

Based on your comments, here is [new the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyG24/25/) that I believe meets your desires. It adds an extra `div` wrapping `.columns` I labeled `.scroller`, and the following css:

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;    
}
.main {
    background: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.main:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 120px; /* match columns */
    background: red;
    z-index: 0;
}

.scroller {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}


.columns {
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    -webkit-column-width: 300px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-width: 300px;
    -moz-column-gap: 40px;
    height: 120px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-align: justify;
    width: auto;
}


.columns > p:last-of-type:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 1px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -20px;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

I use a pseudo-element in `.main` to give the background for `.columns` set to the explicit height you intend for those, then I also use another pseudo-element in the last `p` to force rendering the final 20px of the column. It should work no matter how long or what part it takes up, and at `height: 1px` and `margin-top: -1px` it should not generate a new column if it falls right at the end of a column of text.

### Original Answer: Move Overflow and Set a Right Margin

To get the `background` to transfer, you need to change some CSS, namely:

```css
.main {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.columns {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

This seems to be because the `.column` background is being limited by the `100%` width on the `.main` which is in control of the horizontal scroll bar in your original code. By making `.main` purely hidden, then setting `overflow-x: auto` on `.columns`, the scroll is now controlled by the `.columns` div, and allows its `background` to be seen.

To fix the absence of padding on the far right side, the only think I could come up with was to add the following:

```css
.columns > p:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

This puts a right margin on the last `p` element of the immediate children of `.columns` which then gave the look I assume you are going for.

Here's [the fiddle modified](http://jsfiddle.net/fyG24/5/) (tested only in Firefox).

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific in my example.  I can't add the overflow to columns because its not always as tall as the viewport and I need scroll bar to always be on the bottom.  Depending on screen resolution I am displaying different amounts of content that need to be contained which is why I have the extra parent with the overflow set to it.  

Also I cant put the padding on the last p because its not always just one p tall.  The last column could potentially have more than one p in it.

Comment: @Mike--is all your potential content contained withing `.columns` or is some just inside `.main` or even outside `.main`?

Comment: yes, all of the content is contained within .columns.  I however don't always want the content to take up the entire height of the viewport based on my current grid size at a certain resolution.  So I have a fixed height set on .columns which prevents me from being able to attach the scrollbar to the bottom of the viewport.

Comment: @Mike--okay, I updated with a new answer that I think meets your desires.

Comment: I really only needed the last bit and I modified it a little (didn't need width or display) and added it to .columns:after and not p:after and it seems to work fine.  It's a weird thing to do in order to add some padding but it works.  Thanks.

`.columns:after {
 content: '';
 height: 1px;
 float: right;
 margin-right: -120px;
 margin-top: -1px;
}`

Comment: @Mike--glad I could help lead you to a solution suitable for you.

Comment: I should also note that I was not able to reproduce this in my example but it does work for me in IE10.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved better results just by dividing up your columns css as follows:

```
.columns {
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    -webkit-column-width: 300px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-width: 300px;
    -moz-column-gap: 40px;
    height: 120px;
}
.columns p {
    background: red;
    height: 120px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-align: justify;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: This adds the padding to every p tag which in turn makes each column gap wider.  I also can't just add it to the last p tag because its not always just one paragraph tall like it is in the example.