# CSS(3) columns, multiple ul's

Tags: css, multiple-columns, pseudo-element

i'm working on a horizontal scrolling site. The elements on the site are al placed in a UL > LI structure, to create multiple blocks.

The problem that i am having is the i want 2 sets of UL after eachother, but they will overlap. Tried searching for this on the internet, but none have made what i did.

And example of what i trying to do can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/DHbtx/2/
There you will see that the 2 UL overlap because of the "float: left" and no block elements. i have tried adding an :after pseudo element, but didn't work (from: [Multi-column issue with horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821652/multi-column-issue-with-horizontal-scroll))

```css
li:last-of-type:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 1px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

Could anyone help me with this problem? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the ul elements a width, say 50%.

```
ul
{
  width: 50%;
  ...
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/mTrP5/)**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is that i dont know how long both UL's will be, how many items will be in them. This is all variable...