# Tricking fixed column-width in horizontal scrolling CSS3 Multiple Columns

Tags: html, css

I'm building a horizontal scrolling website that should work with dynamic content. An article is presented in columns via CSS3 Multiple Columns.

With the help from 'ScottS', [as suggested by him in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821652/multi-column-issue-with-horizontal-scroll), that works quite allright. But since I'm beginning an article with an image that takes up about 90% of the pages width,  **the column-width is automatically adjusted to a very small width**, where I would like it to just leave it at 30vw (I don't mind that in that case only a small part of the first column is show, the important thing here is that all the other columns have 30vw width).

I've read that browsers only see a specified column-width as an 'ideal width', adjusting it to the available space on a screen. While I understand why it does that, I still like a way to work around that, if possible.

When I'm not using ScottS's code, and specify the parent div's width in which the columns are shown to, for instance, 4000 pixels, the columns are fine. But I can't do that, since the content is dynamic, so I can't know for sure how lang an article is.

Does anyone have a suggestion how to make it work?

[My fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fyG24/164/).

(Part of) my CSS:

```
html {
height: 100%;
}

body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
height: 100%;    
}

.main {
left:0%;
background: yellow;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
}

.main:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
height: 80vh; 
background: red;
z-index: 0;
}

.scroller {
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow-x: auto;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}

.scroller img {
width:auto;
height:100%;
float:left;
}

.columns {
-webkit-column-fill: auto;
-webkit-column-width: 30vw;
-webkit-column-gap: 40px;
-moz-column-fill: auto;
-moz-column-width: 30vw;
-moz-column-gap: 40px;
height: 80vh;
padding: 0 20px;
text-align: justify;
width: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="main">

<div class="scroller">

        <img src="img/riotclub.jpg">

     <div class="columns">
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ....</p>
      </div>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.scroller {
    width: 200%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @sarah-ha! I tried applying a 200% width to .scroller, and that does seems to make the column wider, but now it just stops scrolling after it reaches the 200% (and when making the width moren that 200% it doesn't scroll at all).