# Fixed header with horizontal scrolling content

Tags: html, css

What I would like to achieve is the following:

- A page header with navigation bar with a fixed height in pixels and stretching the width of the viewport.
- The page content in columns that fill the remaining height of the viewport, and when in overflows it only creates more columns ( not longer ones ) and thus only creating a horizontal scrolling bar that does not scroll the navigation bar.

I based my code mostly on this example [Multi-column issue with horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821652/multi-column-issue-with-horizontal-scroll). But when I try to add the header I always end up with a vertical scroll bar as well. The basic setup looks like this, and a more complete fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e11hLtby/)

```
<div id="navigation">
    NAVIGATION
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div class="scroller">
        <div class="columns">
            CONTENT   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

html, body {
width   :   100%;    
height  :   100%;

margin  :   0;
padding :   0;

display :   table;

color   :   #FFF;
}

#navigation {    
height      :   128px;

display     :   table-row;

background  :   #333;    
}

#content {  
display     :   table-row;  
background  :   #444;
}

.scroller {
height      :   100%;

overflow-x  :   auto;
overflow-y  :   hidden;        
}

.columns {
width   : auto;
height  : 100%;

padding : 0 20px;    

-webkit-column-fill     : auto;
-webkit-column-width    : 300px;
-webkit-column-gap      : 40px;
   -moz-column-fill     : auto;
   -moz-column-width    : 300px;
   -moz-column-gap      : 40px;

text-align  :   justify;    
}
```

Comment: **Where's your CSS?**    Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: fixed;` with `right: 0;` and `left: 0;`. Because you're fixing `#navigation`, you'll need to make sure you add top margining to your `#content` div.

```
#navigation {    
    height: 128px;
    display:    table-row;
    background: #333;   
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

I've revised your fiddle with the suggested changes here http://jsfiddle.net/e11hLtby/1/

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. However, I still end up with a vertical scrolling bar instead of only a horizontal one.

Comment: You've got `height: 100%;` set for your container `.columns`. Set a defined height to it (i.e., 500px;). Here's the revised fiddle for you to review. http://jsfiddle.net/e11hLtby/3/

Comment: Yeah that is because I want to make the content fill all the remaining vertical space, regardless of the viewers window size. Giving it a fixed height is what I don't want. Sorry...

Comment: Then you will want to set absolute positioning on the `.columns` container. Here's the revised fiddle with `height: 100%;` http://jsfiddle.net/e11hLtby/4/

Comment: Hey Chris, I removed the height: 100%; from the .colums because it still made a vertical scrolling bar appear. After that is was perfect. Thank you very much!