# Horizontal Website Scrolling in "React Js"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanna create a horizontal website with ReactJs

if I scroll, I'm going to the next page :)

Here is a mockup layout of what I want to achieve:

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDFxV.png) ,
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFCg7.png)

is there any npm package for creating a horizontal website with react?? like this [oberon.nl](http://oberon.nl)

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixed header with horizontal scrolling content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148359/fixed-header-with-horizontal-scrolling-content)

Comment: is there any npm package for create horizontal website with react like this https://www.oberon.nl/

Comment: i believe react native have some support on this, because it has to preload multiple routes and wire with mouse event.

Comment: You could try https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-horizontal

Comment: thnx @ Ali Klein