# Auto multi-column fixed height issue with horizontal scroll and images

Tags: html, css

based on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821652/multi-column-issue-with-horizontal-scroll)

I am trying to use images in the HTML from the above link. Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6nrpt5eb/3/)

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;        
}
.main {
    background: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.columns {
    background: red;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    -webkit-column-width: 300px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-width: 300px;
    -moz-column-gap: 40px;
    height: 120px;
    padding: 0 20px;

    width: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.columns img{
  height:none;
  display: block; 
}
.columns > p:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Horizontal scrolling works great, but the image gets divided into `columns` as well. I didn't know that this is even possible. I like it to stay in one part with the `height` of the column and auto `width` not with the column width. So that the `columns` coming after it gets shifted.

Answer (score 0):

I think I find a possible way to realize what I wanted.
Now it uses a bit JS and Jquery. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nrpt5eb/5/).

Main point is to check page.offsetHeight < page.scrollHeight to see if the textfield has overflow. When it has create a new div.

Here is the JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".element2" ).each(function( i,obj ) {
            if(this.tagName == "IMG"){
                $("#paginatedText").append(obj);
            }else{
                paginateText(obj);
            }

            console.log(this.tagName);
  });



    function paginateText(element) {
        //console.log(element);
        var text = $(element).html(); // gets the text, which should be displayed later on
        //console.log(text);

        var textArray = text.split(" "); // makes the text to an array of words
        createPage(); // creates the first page
        for (var i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) { // loops through all the words
                //$( ".element" ).last().append(textArray[i]);
                var success = appendToLastPage(textArray[i]); // tries to fill the word in the last page
                if (!success) { // checks if word could not be filled in last page
                        createPage(); // create new empty page
                        appendToLastPage(textArray[i]); // fill the word in the new last element
                }
        }
    }

    function createPage() {
    var page = document.createElement("div"); // creates new html element
    page.setAttribute("class", "page"); // appends the class "page" to the element
    document.getElementById("paginatedText").appendChild(page); // appends the element to the container for all the pages
    }

    function appendToLastPage(word) {
    var page = document.getElementsByClassName("page")[document.getElementsByClassName("page").length - 1]; // gets the last page
    var pageText = page.innerHTML; // gets the text from the last page
    page.innerHTML += word + " "; // saves the text of the last page
    if (page.offsetHeight < page.scrollHeight) { // checks if the page overflows (more words than space)
            page.innerHTML = pageText; //resets the page-text
            return false; // returns false because page is full
    } else {
            return true; // returns true because word was successfully filled in the page
    }
    }

});
```